# xhtml2pdf Pisa css broken Unknown color False

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to generate a PDF using html+css using xhtml2pdf.pisa using Django. However, I'm running into all sorts of weird issues with the CSS.

Below is my code:

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

And my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example 2</title>
    <style>
      
      @font-face {
  font-family: SourceSansPro;
  src: url(SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf);
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

a {
  color: #0087C3;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  width: 21cm;  
  height: 29.7cm; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  color: #555555;
  background: #FFFFFF; 
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
  font-size: 14px; 
  font-family: SourceSansPro;
}

header {
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

#logo img {
  height: 70px;
}

#company {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}


#details {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#client {
  padding-left: 6px;
  border-left: 6px solid #0087C3;
  float: left;
}

#client .to {
  color: #777777;
}

h2.name {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

#invoice {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

#invoice h1 {
  color: #0087C3;
  font-size: 2.4em;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0  0 10px 0;
}

#invoice .date {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #777777;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #EEEEEE;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

table th {
  white-space: nowrap;        
  font-weight: normal;
}

table td {
  text-align: right;
}

table td h3{
  color: #57B223;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 0 0.2em 0;
}

table .no {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  background: #57B223;
}

table .desc {
  text-align: left;
}

table .unit {
  background: #DDDDDD;
}

table .qty {
}

table .total {
  background: #57B223;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

table td.unit,
table td.qty,
table td.total {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

table tbody tr:last-child td {
  border: none;
}

table tfoot td {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  border-top: 1px solid #AAAAAA; 
}

table tfoot tr:first-child td {
  border-top: none; 
}

table tfoot tr:last-child td {
  color: #57B223;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  border-top: 1px solid #57B223; 

}

table tfoot tr td:first-child {
  border: none;
}

#thanks{
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#notices{
  padding-left: 6px;
  border-left: 6px solid #0087C3;  
}

#notices .notice {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

footer {
  color: #777777;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  padding: 8px 0;
  text-align: center;
}


    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="clearfix">
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="logo.png">
      </div>
      <div id="company">
        <h2 class="name">Company Name</h2>
        <div>455 Foggy Heights, AZ 85004, US</div>
        <div>(602) 519-0450</div>
        <div><a href="mailto:company@example.com">company@example.com</a></div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div id="details" class="clearfix">
        <div id="client">
          <div class="to">INVOICE TO:</div>
          <h2 class="name">John Doe</h2>
          <div class="address">796 Silver Harbour, TX 79273, US</div>
          <div class="email"><a href="mailto:john@example.com">john@example.com</a></div>
        </div>
        <div id="invoice">
          <h1>INVOICE 3-2-1</h1>
          <div class="date">Date of Invoice: 01/06/2014</div>
          <div class="date">Due Date: 30/06/2014</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="no">#</th>
            <th class="desc">DESCRIPTION</th>
            <th class="unit">UNIT PRICE</th>
            <th class="qty">QUANTITY</th>
            <th class="total">TOTAL</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="no">01</td>
            <td class="desc"><h3>Website Design</h3>Creating a recognizable design solution based on the company's existing visual identity</td>
            <td class="unit">$40.00</td>
            <td class="qty">30</td>
            <td class="total">$1,200.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="no">02</td>
            <td class="desc"><h3>Website Development</h3>Developing a Content Management System-based Website</td>
            <td class="unit">$40.00</td>
            <td class="qty">80</td>
            <td class="total">$3,200.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="no">03</td>
            <td class="desc"><h3>Search Engines Optimization</h3>Optimize the site for search engines (SEO)</td>
            <td class="unit">$40.00</td>
            <td class="qty">20</td>
            <td class="total">$800.00</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2">SUBTOTAL</td>
            <td>$5,200.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2">TAX 25%</td>
            <td>$1,300.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2">GRAND TOTAL</td>
            <td>$6,500.00</td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
      <div id="thanks">Thank you!</div>
      <div id="notices">
        <div>NOTICE:</div>
        <div class="notice">A finance charge of 1.5% will be made on unpaid balances after 30 days.</div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      Invoice was created on a computer and is valid without the signature and seal.
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

My code is pretty basic and nothing special, they are just pretty much copied verbatim from the web

I cannot observe a pattern from these symptoms other than just thinking the css parser and layout engine is just totally incomplete and non-functional. However I cannot find anyone online who has the same issues as me. Am I crazy? I'm not sure what is happening here... any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue I had this line:

- `.f1,input,textarea{border:1px solid #000;}`

Which would cause the issue adding an extra 0 fixed it for me.

- `.f1,input,textarea{border:1px solid #0000;}`

edit:

I also have this in my style

- `black{background-color:#000;}`
- `.white{background-color:#fff;}`

For some reason having the **background** color value have four characters will cause the error and having the **solid** less than four will cause the same error.